# Trying to add a load event into an anchor alement (JQuery)

Tags: jquery

I´ve tried to add .load() to an anchor tag to handle the event when the anchor loads.

So I´ve tried like this:

```
$("a.sorting_right").load(function(){$(this).html("Test");});
```

When the anchor tag loads it don´t get the text "Test" in it.

What I´m doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: An anchor tag doesn't really load, it has no onload event, only images, the window and certain other elements that actually load has a load event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.load` is used to load content from somewhere else on your server, it is *not* used as an element on load trigger. Use a DOM ready statement.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.sorting_right").html("Test");
});
```

Comment: Using it as a "load" handler was [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) in version 1.8

Comment: Deprecated because it was confusing, but not removed. Instead it was recommended to use `on` as that handles any event, including the `load` event